# Windows 10 Virtual Desktops - Shortcut to “enable” / “activate” a program after desktop switch

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, productivity

I really like the new virtual desktop feature in windows 10. It really improves my work productivity. However I have one issue I cannot find to fix.

I simplify my problem here a little bit:

I have 2 virtual Desktops. Desktop 1 contains a browser (displaying stackoverflow.com obviously ;) ).

Desktop 2 contains my IDE.

I switch quite often between those 2 desktops. I have to press Win + Strgt + Left/Right Arrow to switch desktops. When I switch from desktop 1 to desktop 2, I want to instantly be able to start writing code in my IDE, but this is not possible, because I have to "enable" or "activate" the window at first (by clicking into the programm with my mouse). I want to get rid of using my mouse and just leave my hands on the keyboard in this case. Is there some kind of possibility (shortcut) to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via keyboard shortcuts as you request. One solution is:

1. Once you have switched to your desired desktop
2. Use alt+tab to switch to your IDE
3. If the code pane is not active within your IDE you will need to use another keyboard shortcut to switch to it