# Windows Shortcut/Utility to switch between application windows in different virtual desktops

Tags: windows

I have a number of virtual desktops with applications running in each.  I have found an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/699846/364369) that addresses the ability to switch between instances of a running application but this doesn't work when the application is open on another virtual desktop.  For example, I have Outlook pinned in taskbar slot 1 and if Outlook is open in Virtual desktop #1 and I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> while in Virtual desktop #2 it opens a new instance of Outlook instead of switching to the one that's open in Virtual desktop #1.  Is it possible to switch to a running application in another desktop with a keyboard shortcut?

Please note this question is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/987942/364369).  I'm looking for a solution that can directly switch and focus the application in another virtual desktop via a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using multiple virtual desktops, Alt+Tab will only switch
between the apps on the current desktop by default.
But you can change this behavior to switch between apps on all desktops,
as follows.

- Run *Settings > System*
- Choose Multi-tasking
- Under "Virtual desktops", for
  "Pressing Alt+Tab shows windows that are open on",
  click the drop-down box and change the default
  "Only the desktop I’m using" to  "All desktops"
- The effect is immediate.

From now on, Alt+Tab will switch between all applications.